# Npm audit fixes causing build failure

Tags: angular

I am trying to resolve an npm audit issue where loader-utils and terser are causing the problem in the angular 14 application I am maintaining.

The problem is this:
https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-4wf5-vphf-c2xc

I've tried:

1. npm audit fix -force
2. npm install terser@latest
3. npm install loader-utils@latest
4. in package.json under resolutions, i added both "terser" and "loader-utils", then ran npx npm-force-resolutions

So now i have not audit problems but the project will not build:

```
[error] TypeError: Ajv is not a constructor
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Projects\scenic.booking.portal.ui\node_modules\mini-css-extract-plugin\node_modules\schema-utils\dist\validate.js:66:13)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Projects\scenic.booking.portal.ui\node_modules\mini-css-extract-plugin\node_modules\schema-utils\dist\index.js:6:5)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
```

Can anyone help me here as everything from here is just introducing more errors when trying to build the application?

---

Versions:

1. npm: 9.1.2
2. @angular-devkit/core: 14.0.1
3. rxjs: 7.5.5
4. typescript: 4.73

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do not use `-force`  when you use `npm audit fix` otherwise incompatible dependencies will be installed.

depending on your version of Angular you need to find the correct dependecies.
Check the documentation to know wich version is compatible.

To solve your problem right now:

- uninstall the packages that are problematic (i.e. `mini-css-extract-plugin`)
- delete the node_modules folder and `package-lock.json`
- run `npm install`
- install again the packages (right version)
- never use `-force` unless you know what you are doing